# How to make 3D array in BASH?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, multidimensional-array

I want to write/make/use a 3D array of [m][n][k] in BASH. From what I understand, BASH does not support array that are not 1D.

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fake multi-dimensionality with a crafted associative array key:

```
declare -A ary
for i in 1 2 3; do 
    for j in 4 5 6; do 
        for k in 7 8 9; do 
            ary["$i,$j,$k"]=$((i*j*k))
        done
    done
done
for key in "${!ary[@]}"; do printf "%s\t%d\n" "$key" "${ary[$key]}"; done | sort
```

```
1,4,7   28
1,4,8   32
1,4,9   36
1,5,7   35
1,5,8   40
1,5,9   45
1,6,7   42
1,6,8   48
1,6,9   54
2,4,7   56
2,4,8   64
2,4,9   72
2,5,7   70
2,5,8   80
2,5,9   90
2,6,7   84
2,6,8   96
2,6,9   108
3,4,7   84
3,4,8   96
3,4,9   108
3,5,7   105
3,5,8   120
3,5,9   135
3,6,7   126
3,6,8   144
3,6,9   162
```

I used `sort` because keys of an assoc.array have no inherent order.

Answer (score 3):

You can use associative arrays if your bash is recent enough:

```
unset assoc
declare -A assoc
assoc["1.2.3"]=x
```

But, I'd rather switch to a language that supports multidimensional arrays (e.g. Perl).

Comment: Good practice is to `unset assoc` before using `declare` because it'll cause an error if `assoc` is already a non-associative array. (i.e. `foo=(1,2,3); declare -A foo` causes an error)

Answer (score 1):

As in C, you can simulate multidimensional array using an offset.

```
#! /bin/bash

xmax=100
ymax=150
zmax=80
xymax=$((xmax*ymax))
vol=()

for ((z=0; z<zmax; z++)); do
for ((y=0; y<ymax; y++)); do
for ((x=0; x<xmax; x++)); do
    ((t = z*xymax+y*xmax+x))
    if ((vol[t] == 0)); then
        ((vol[t] = vol[t-xymax] + vol[t-ymax] + vol[t-1]))
    fi
done
done
done
```